# Converting <br> Tags to <Div> or <P> Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am receiving HTML that is in various formats and I'm trying to standardize the code using jQuery. In some cases I receive it using breaks `<br>` to separate lines. I need these to be `<div>` (or `<p>`) tags instead. For instance the following code:

```
a<br>b<br>c
```

needs to be converted into

```
<div>a</div><div>b</div><div>c</div>
```

This is a simple case as the contents in `a` could be surrounded by all kinds of `<font>`, `<span>` and other formatting options, all of which need to be retained.

Here was my first attempt. It finds all the `<br>` tags in the entire document then accesses the parent's contents to get all the HTML around the `<br>`. If the contents length is 1 then `<br>` is the only element in there (meaning a blank line) so skip on to the next one. Otherwise look at each element, surround it with `<div>` (or `<p>`) and remove the `<br>` as it isn't needed any more. Variable `wrapper` is either `"<div />"` or `"<p />"` depending on the browser.

```
$("br").each(function() {
  // Find all the br tags' parent nodes
  var elements = $(this).parent().contents();
  if (elements.length > 1) {
    // If there is one element than it is br so skip on.
    elements.each(function() {
      // Loop through each child element of the parent 
      var nodeName = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      if (nodeName !== 'div' && nodeName !== 'p') {
      // Make sure each child that is not <br> is wrapped. Remove <br> tags.
        if (nodeName == 'br') {
          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          $(this).wrap(wrapper);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This doesn't work, though, as it adds `<div>` (or `<p>`) tags around every sub-element so something like `<font>a</font>bc<br>de<b>f</b>` ends up like

```
<div><font>a</font></div>
<div>bc</div>
<div>de</div>
<div><b>f</b></div>
```

when it really needs to be

```
<div><font>a</font>bc</div>
<div>de<b>f</b></div>
```

(I broke it up to be easier to read.)

If I was doing this in a text parser, I'd find the contents just like I did above for variable `elements`, add a `<div>` at the beginning and a `</div>` at the end, then replace each `<br>` with `</div><div>` (except when it is already `<div><br></div>`, at which point I'd skip it). I have no idea how to do this in jQuery/Javascript. though, especially regarding the replace `<br>` with `</div><div>` portion. (The first part is `elements.wrap(wrapper)`.)

Any help on this approach or an alternative approach would be appreciated.

--- UPDATE ---

@Ian supplied must of the code that worked. I expanded on it just a little and thought I'd include it here. I have tested it in FF, Safari, Chrome and IE 9+.

```
$("br").each(function(idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el),
        $parent = $el.parent(),
        $contents = $parent.contents(),
        $cur, $set, i;

    $set = $();
        if ($contents.length > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < $contents.length; i++) {
            $cur = $contents.eq(i);

            if ($cur.is("br")) {
                $set.wrapAll(wrapper);
                $cur.remove();
                $set = $();
            } else {
                $set = $set.add($cur);
            }
        }
        $set.wrapAll(wrapper);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @TimurShahbanov. Can you be more specific? What are you thinking regarding prepend()?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight $(this).wrap(wrapper) adds the <div> or <p> as explained in my description.

Comment: I think this more or less is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/GV9fL/ . Mess around with the HTML and make sure it works as you expect (checking your browser's developer tool's DOM inspector). It doesn't use any ridiculous text/html parsing/rebuilding. But it's a little sloppy and could probably be reorganized better

Comment: @Ian This is the winner with one modification, at least in all my various Safari examples. I still need to test on other browsers. I wish I could upvote you. I wrapped the for loop in an if ($contents.length > 1) to make sure we weren't removing a legitimate blank row: <div><br></div>.

Comment: Thanks for the question and @Ian for the answer.  I'll point out two things: (1) it throws out breaks in a row like `<br><br>` so if that was intended as some special thing that intention is lost and (2) I'm not sure what passing `<div \>` will do in HTML5 but at least `<div />` [isn't a synonym for `<div></div>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).  So I'm going with `<div></div>`... :-/

Comment: @HostileFork In my experience, contenteditable won't return <br><br> if the initial setup is correct. Of course the initial setup varies by browser, though. Safari and Chrome start with <div><br></div>, IE starts with <div></div> and FF starts with <p><br></p>. From that point foreward, all rows will be wrapped in the appropriate <div> or <p>.

Comment: @eliajf The question is phrased a bit more abstractly *("I am receiving HTML that is in various formats")* and lays out a problem with a solution...no mention of contenteditable until you brought it up!  :-)  In my case, it *does* so happen I'm messing with a contenteditable... but the `<br>` series are being created by me from flattening some data.  So I can get `<br><br><br>` etc.  Just raising a point about an edge case.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion will be to split the text by `<br>`:

```
var lines = content.split("<br>");
```

Now you can wrap each line in a `<div>`:

```
var newContent = "";
for(var i=0,l=lines.length;i<l;i++){
     newContent += "<div>"+lines[i]+"</div>";

}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is sort of like parsing html with regex.  In the general case this will work but you could come up with ways to break it pretty easily.

Comment: As @JamesMontagne points out, an example of a case that breaks is <div>a<div><br></div></div>.

Comment: my example will not create br tags. Try it and show me how it fails. The example you gave is in contradiction with what you asked on your main question. Why is it surrounded by divs?

Comment: I'm not quite certain how to handle this. Yours, PeterOlson's and funkwurm's code all technically work in some cases but not all cases. I did upvote all three. Turns out <br> tags can't just be replaced. There are cases where the tags must persist as they are how the code is formed. An example is <div>a</div><div><br></div><div>b</div>. This is how a <blank row> b is represented. Your code removes the blank row completely. @Ian in the comments wrote the jsfiddle version that is closest to working in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the exact text replacement method that you described.

```
function changeBrToDiv(node) {
  var html = $(node).html();
  html = "<div>" + html.split("<br>").join("</div><div>") + "</div>";
  node.html(html);
}
```

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpyFK/1/).

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like you may want to leave the `br` tags in the DOM until you are done traversing it.  In the case of your second example, you won't know how high to reach with the opening `div` tag unless you have left the `br` tag in as a reference point.  I would grab the parent element, look up the DOM til you either find the opening `<body>` or a `<br>` and then slap the opening tag there.  Rinse and repeat

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` tags don't contain the text, and the parent tag is possibly the exact same for multiple `<br>`s like here:

```
<div id="theOne">text<br>more text<br>even more text</div>
```

Doing `$('br').each()` and then `$(this).parent()` is gonna give you the `<div id="theOne">` twice.

If you are OK with approaching the html as text you could do this (similar to Ibu but simpler):

```
var newContent = '<div>'+content.split('<br>').join('</div><div>')+'</div>';
```

If you wanna use node manipulation (you downvoted a similar answer) then you'll have to use the native Javascript `.childNodes` to access textnodes, jQuery doesn't let you do that as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your problem:

```
var elements = $(this).parent().contents();
```

should be

```
var elements = $(this).parent().children();
```

since contents returns text elements as nodes as well, whereas children will only return the actual dom elements

Comment: Changing to children() gets me the element nodes but not the text nodes. Thanks, though.

Comment: @eliajf but y do you want the text nodes?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight You are correct that I want the children nodes in a revised version. In the one I wrote above, though, grabbing children() only wouldn't do the trick. In that case I needed the text and element nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in POJS; manipulate the DOM rather than treat your markup as text. You may need to modify it slightly to suit your exact requirements.

HTML

```
<div>one
    <br>two</div>
<br>
<div>
    <br>
</div>
<div>
    <div>three
        <br><font>a</font>bc
        <br>de<b>f</b>

    </div>
</div>
<span>a</span>

<br>b<span>c</span>d
<br>e<span>f</span>g
```

Javascript

```
function prepend(referenceNode, newNode) {
    if (referenceNode.firstChild) {
        referenceNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.firstChild);
    } else {
        referenceNode.appendChild(newNode);
    }
}

var brs = document.getElementsByTagName("br"),
    docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    index1,
    index2,
    parent,
    siblings,
    sibling,
    br;

for (index1 = brs.length - 1; index1 >= 0; index1 -= 1) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    br = brs[index1];
    parent = br.parentNode;
    siblings = parent.childNodes;
    for (index2 = siblings.length - 1; index2 >= 0; index2 -= 1) {
        sibling = siblings[index2];
        if (sibling === br) {
            break;
        }

        prepend(div, sibling);
    }

    prepend(docFragment, div);
    br.parentNode.removeChild(br);
    if (!brs.length && siblings.length) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        for (index2 = siblings.length - 1; index2 >= 0; index2 -= 1) {
            prepend(div, siblings[index2]);
        }

        prepend(docFragment, div);
    }

    if (docFragment.childNodes.length && !siblings.length) {
        parent.appendChild(docFragment);
    }
}
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Vw65a/)</kbd>